# How to subtract datetimes with python

Tags: python, datetime

Today =

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

90days ago

```
DD = datetime.timedelta(days=-90)
```

How do I get today - DD, or 90days ago?

Comment: where did you learn about `datetime` module and `timedelta` class in particular?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should be able to subtract time deltas from datetime objects.

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
DD = datetime.timedelta(days=90)
earlier = today - DD
earlier_str = earlier.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 16):

Just subtract a timedelta from a datetime:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> DD = datetime.timedelta(days=90)
>>> today - DD
datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 3, 9, 56, 20, 924224)
```

(or if you want to use a negative timedelta like you did there, add them:

```
>>> DD = datetime.timedelta(days=-90)
>>> today + DD
datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 3, 9, 56, 20, 924224)
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to subtract `timedelta(days=90)`:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.now()
dd = today - timedelta(days=90) 
print(dd)
```

It should [print](http://ideone.com/17fIF) `2010-11-03 15:04:42.289684`.

Comment: A couple of seconds ago, it was `2010-11-03 15:04:42.289684`.

Comment: well, my question wasn't asked couple of seconds ago, now was it?

Comment: No, you are right, back then, it had an error -- an extra `strftime` --, but it is fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

currentDay = date.today()

requestedDay = currentDay - timedelta(days=90)

print(requestedDay)
```

hope it solves.