# How to subtract n number of days from a given date in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have implemented the database as follows

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

class Medicine:
 id =  db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
 exp_date = db.DateProperty()
```

and in entity manager i want to get all the medicines where expiry date - 20

```
MedicineEntity:
 def get_medicines(self):
 query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Medicine WHERE exp_date=:1", exp_date -20 )
```

I know that my query is wrong . is there a way to get the difference like sql in Gql. Can any one help?

Comment: You have two choices, and search will reveal answers to both.  (1) do date arithmetic outside SQL (i.e., compute the new date) or (2) do date arithmetic in SQL (i.e., subtract exp_date from today.)  Try searching for SQL date difference and Python date difference for the approaches.

Comment: Im looking for Gql and im still searching a way

Comment: Where is `exp_date` getting set in `get_medicines()` (and are you sure you want to manually set an `id` field in your model)?

Comment: @S.Lott He is doing his math outside the GQL.

Comment: Wooble is right, though - you almost certainly shouldn't be creating an 'id' field - use the built in key instead.

Comment: @NickJohnson: That's far from obvious.  And.  If it's true, it's a well-answered question.  Date arithmetic in Python is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863994/how-to-subtract-dates-with-python

Comment: @S.Lott Obvious or not, it's the case. Parameters to Python functions - any python function - are processed before the function is called, so `exp_date-20` is evaluated before `GqlQuery` is called.

Comment: @NickJohnson: "Parameters to Python functions ... are processed before the function is called"  Totally true.  But not the **only** approach to this query.  It would be entirely possible to tackle this doing the math in the query instead of the app.

Comment: @S.Lott No it wouldn't, because GQL does not support arbitrary expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way of doing this in python is using timedelta.

eg:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
delta = timedelta(days=20)

then = now - delta
```

So 1 option would be to convert exp_date into a datetime, subtract the timedelta and then convert it back to a dateproperty.

I haven't used appengine so I don't know how hard that would be exactly.

**edit**: Some searching shows that DateProperty actually stores the value as a datetime object, so it should be as simple as

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Medicine WHERE exp_date=:1", exp_date - timedelta(days=20) )
```