# how to subtract date from date from sql in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, date-arithmetic

I run a sql query that returns a date in the format `'2015-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'` I want to subtract this from today's date.

I am getting today's date with the following:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

The formats don't seem to line up and I can't figure out a standardize format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to subtract dates with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863994/how-to-subtract-dates-with-python)

Comment: You should probably edit the subject to something like "how to subtract date from date from sql in python"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strptime` from datetime module to get python compatible date time from your query result using a format string. (You might have to play with the format string a bit to suit your case)

```
ts = '2015-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000' to a format string like
f = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
date_from_sql = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, f)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = date_from_sql - now
```

The .000 is probably microseconds (denoted by %f in the format string) and the +0000 is the utc offset (denoted by %z in the format string). Check this out for more formatting options: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Check out this thread for an example: [what is the proper way to convert between mysql datetime and python timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291636/what-is-the-proper-way-to-convert-between-mysql-datetime-and-python-timestamp)

Checkout this for more on strptime https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Thanks, I read the resources and it makes sense, but I get the error: `ValueError: unconverted data remains: .000+0000`

Comment: The .000 is probably microseconds (denoted by %f in the format string) and the +0000 is the utc offset (denoted by %z in the format string). I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the **delta** between two datetime objects in Python is really simple, you simply subtract them.

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
d2 = datetime.datetime.now()

delta = d2 - d1
print delta.total_seconds()
```

`d2 - d1` returns a datetime.timedelta object, from which you can get the total second difference between the two dates.

As for formatting the dates, you can read about formatting **strings into datetime objects**, and **datetime objects into string** [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

You'll read about the strftime() and strptime() functions, and with them you can get yourself two datetime objects which you can subtract from each other.