# Date Boundaries with Python's date.strftime

Tags: python

I am really new to Python and I am trying to define two boundary dates `start_period_date` and the `end_period_date`. The current snippet of code prints this on to a GNU plot graph.

Python Code:

```
        end_period_date = date.strftime( "%A %d %b %Y")
        goBack = timedelta(days=8)
        start_period_date = end_period_date - goBack
        print( "set label 1 \"" + machine_name + "\\nWeekly Utilization Graph " + start_period_date + " till " +  end_period_date +"\" at graph 0,1.125 left", file=f )
```

The output is (top) but I want the output to be the bottom 12 April:[image]

I have tried looking at various [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863994/how-to-subtract-dates-with-python) but I can't seem to see my error.
Any suggestions or any other alternatives?

Comment: It looks like you're subtracting a timedelta from a string, not a date object

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
import datetime 
end_period_date = datetime.date.today()
start_period_date = end_period_date - datetime.timedelta(days=8)
print end_period_date.strftime("%A %d %b %Y")
print start_period_date.strftime("%A %d %b %Y")
```

Output:

```
Wednesday 20 Apr 2016 
Tuesday 12 Apr 2016
```

Make sure your end_period_date is date not string. May be will help you.